# Get list of struct all array and detect the name of each array auto and print it

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

This is my program

```
struct All_Modules
{
    char* Name;
};

All_Modules First_Array[] = { { "hi\n" } };
All_Modules Next_Array[]  = { { "hi1\n" } };
All_Modules Other_Array[] = { { "hi2\n" } };

int main()
{
}
```

Is there way to get list of `All_Modules` all array name like (`First_Array`,...) and show print them like this?

```
My array is : First_Array | and The of This array is : hi
My array is : Next_Array | and The of This array is : hi1
My array is : Other_Array | and The of This array is : hi2
```

I know we can set each array to print this but I want first system get the list of all array in `All_Modules` and detect the names and automatic print the `Name` value... Is it possible?

Comment: You make an awful lot of questions just in your title. Which of the several steps do you have a problem with? Please adjust your question so that this becomes obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is possible, but you have to implement it by yourself using static members.

In the constructor of `All_Modules` append newly created instance to a global (static) list.

```
struct All_Modules{
  char* Name;

  All_Modules(){
    gModulesList.push_back(this);
  };

  static void print_all(){
    for(... gModulesList ...){
      // print gModulesList[i]->Name;
    }
  };

private:
  static std::list<All_Modules*> gModulesList;  
};
```

Comment: when i want to add an array from All_Modules, i see this error 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'All_Modules' Project2

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you would have to enumerate all global variables for those of a certain type, but C++ doesn't offer a way for that (it's called introspection, BTW). There might be some compiler-specific ways to get at that info though, but they won't be portable.